# PDO - как включить вывод сообщений об ошибках?

Tags: php, pdo

В конструкторе класса для работы с БД устанавливаю атрибут

```
$this->pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);
```

Однако никаких ошибок не выводится (хотя они есть).

В частности

```
$sql = "select count(*) from `punbb_users` where `username` = ? limit 1";
$params = 'somebody';
$stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute($params);
```

Не выдает ошибки, хотя и не выполняется, так как `$params` - не массив.

В чем может быть проблема? (другие предупреждения выводятся, то есть режим их вывода включен).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Лучше включить режим выдачи исключений

```
<?php
$pdo = new PDO(
  'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test',
  'root',
  '',
  [PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION]);
```

Comment: и отловить их `try { }catch(Exception $error) {}`

Comment: C выводом предупреждений я разобрался - там мой косяк был (режим выдачи предупреждений все же не был включен, или отключался где то по ходу жизни), а вот сделать выдачу исключений по Вашему совету не удалось.Также как я понял - даже если ничего не устанавливать, предупреждения все равно выводятся. Может ли быть, что что-то в каких то глобальных настройках не дает выбрасывать исключения? То есть у меня получается, что эта установка атрибутов вообще ни на что не влияет.

Comment: @Naumov при чем здесь "отловить"? В вопросе явно написано, как включить **вывод**, а не "отловить". РНР прекрасно выведет все ошибки и сам, без ваших костылей в виде try { }catch(Exception. Отлов исключениия - это совершенно отдельная операция, которая требуется относительно редко, когда надо обработать ошибку, а не вывести. К информированию программиста об ошибках она не имеет никакого отношения.